# why this output is come in java program?

Tags: java, arrays

[image]I make Constructor of String as--

```
class TestString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      int arr[]={1,5,6,8,9};

      String str3 = new String(arr,1,3);//public java.lang.String(int[], int, int);

      System.out.println(str3);
   }
}
```

output is in image I can't understand its meaning....

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. You're passing an array of integers into a String object, what are you expecting, numbers back? The constructor API describes what is happening: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've created a string consisting of three Unicode code points, [U+0005](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0005/index.htm), [U+0006](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0006/index.htm) and [U+0008](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm), and I bet your output is showing exactly that (it is on my machine).

**edit** Your console is using a particular font to render the output. Apparently, the font contains the suit pictograms for characters with codes 5 and 6. I recognize these as going back all the way to the original IBM PC: http://www.ascii-codes.com/

Comment: means it will produce unicode value?

Comment: Cool... I was not knowing this (might be because I never dare to touch String class)

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer....

Comment: Oh those are some adorable glyphs. Takes me back.

Answer (score 2):

You craeted a String using the byte array constructor. The byte array must contain the Unicode-points. See [ascii table](http://ss64.com/ascii.html) for more information on unicode points and there representative values.

Answer (score 1):

They array should contain Unicode codePoints. Do you know what 5, 6, and 8 mean?
It concatenates Unicode characters with the codes you pass in your array, starting at offset 1, with length three. So, offset 1 is the second element of the array (5). It takes 3 elements: 5, 6, and 8. Those characters represent the funny looking graphics you see in your screen

Comment: how I can get Int value from that?

Comment: do you want to concatenate 5, 6, 8 into a string?

Comment: I want to know exactlly what is working of this String Constructor?

Comment: It concatenates Unicode characters with the codes you pass in your array, starting at offset 1, with length three. So, offset 1 is the second element of the array (5). It takes 3 elements: 5, 6, and 8. Those characters represent the funny looking graphics you see in your screen

Comment: Can you edit the details from the comments into the answer please?  Thanks.